# How can I add exlude list items to windows batch codes

Tags: windows, file, batch-file

```
set exludelist= foldername1 foldername2 foldername3
pushd "%workdir%"
for /d %%f in (*) do (
   will do somestuff here...
)
popd
```

So I how can I check foldername in for loop for above EXCLUDE list? If current folder name is in exludelist, it should pass to next one. With an nested if statement? Or something else?

Comment: Replace your existing `for` command line by `for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir /AD /B 2^>nul ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /I /L /X /V /C:"foldername1" /C:"folder name 2" /C:"& one more folder name"') do (`. Open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/), run `dir /?` and `findstr /?` and `for /?` and read each output help carefully from top of first to bottom of last page to understand how command `dir` is used to search for directories with filtering the directories list with `findstr` and processing the filtered directories list with `for`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "excludeList=|foldername1|foldername2|foldername3|"
pushd "%workdir%"
for /d %%f in (*) do (
   if "!excludeList:|%%f|=!" equ "%excludeList%" (
      will do somestuff here...
   )
)
popd
```

In the `!excludeList:|%%f|=!` variable expansion, if the `%%f` folder name *is* in the exclude list, then the expansion will be *different* than the original `%excludeList%` string. This means that if the expansion is the same than before, then `%%f` is not excluded, so...

The `|` delimiters are inserted just to avoid that an excluded name could appear *as part* of another valid, longer name.